# Spring Pessimistic locking

Tags: java, database, hibernate, transactions, pessimistic-locking

i have spring project under java, using hibernate query, i like to use pessimistic locking.

How to do Pessimistic locking in Spring + Hibernate?

**Edit:**

```
@Loggable(value = LogLevel.TRACE)
@Transactional
@Override
public void updateBalance(String id, BigDecimal amount) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.flush();
    Account acc = (Account) session.get(Account.class, id, LockMode.UPGRADE);
    acc.setName("New Account");
    acc.setBalance(acc.getBalance().subtract(amount));
    save(acc);
    try{
        tx.commit();
    }catch (TransactionException e){
        tx.rollback();
    }
    session.close();
}
```

**Problem:**

i want to use pessimistic locking in a method, and i call this method from different to methods. pessimistic works fine when i call it from the first method, but it gives (Transaction couldn't be commit) when i call it from the second method

**Exception:**

```
Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.
TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
```

Comment: Google "*Pessimistic locking in Spring + Hibernate*" and get: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-locking

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: there's nothing about _Spring_ in that link.

Comment: I can see some bad Practices(rather mistakes) here 1) Opening a new Transaction in the method at the same time using @Transactional on top of method 2)Opening a new Session(`sessionFactory.openSession();` while using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` before that 3)Closing the Current Session Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.amicabile.com/hybernate/hybernate-chapter5.html

http://javacompleteexamples.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-db-locking-system-works-in.html

**Edit:**

try:

```
@Override
@Loggable(value = LogLevel.TRACE)
@Transactional
public void updateBalance(String id, BigDecimal amount) {
        Account acc = (Account) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Account.class, id, LockMode.UPGRADE);
        acc.setBalance(acc.getBalance().subtract(amount));
        save(acc);
}
```

Comment: i want to use pessimistic locking in a method, and i call this method from different to methods. i read these links, i solve the problem. but there is another problem, pessimistic works fine when i call it from the first method, but it gives (Transaction couldn't be commit) when i call it from the second method